# Merging multiple Pyspark columns into a single one if they are not Null

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a Pyspark dataframe by merging multiple column values into a single json column. Though I only want to create the mapping if both col3 and col4 values are not Null. If they contain Null values then the col5 value should be Null too.

```
df = df.select("col1", "col2", struct(*[col(c) for c in ["col3", "col4"]]).alias("col5"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resort to `when().otherwise()`.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('json_str', 
               func.when(func.col('c1').isNull() | func.col('c2').isNull(), func.lit(None)).
               otherwise(func.to_json(func.struct('c1', 'c2')))
               ). \
    show()

# +---+----+---------------+
# | c1|  c2|       json_str|
# +---+----+---------------+
# |  1|   1|{"c1":1,"c2":1}|
# |  2|null|           null|
# +---+----+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using `when` and replacing structs with `MapType` and `to_json`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, create_map, when, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType

df = df.withColumn(
    "col5",
    when(
        df.col4.isNotNull() & df.col3.isNotNull(),
        create_map("col4", "col5")
    ).otherwise(lit(None).cast(MapType()))
    
# Then for the JSON simply do:
df = df.withColumn(
    "col5",
    to_json("col5"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `case+when` statement and create the json.

**`Method1:`**

If you want schema consistency with col3,col4 for `null` col5 value then use this method.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data
#+----+----+----+----+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|
#+----+----+----+----+
#|a   |null|d   |e   |
#|a   |b   |null|e   |
#|a   |z   |d   |null|
#|a   |null|null|null|
#+----+----+----+----+

df.withColumn("col5",
when((col("col3").isNotNull()) & (col("col4").isNotNull()),struct(*[col(c) for c in ["col3", "col4"]])).\
otherwise(struct(*[lit(None).cast("string").alias(c) for c in ["col3", "col4"]]))).\
show(10)

#output
#+----+----+----+----+------------+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|        col5|
#+----+----+----+----+------------+
#|   a|null|   d|   e|      {d, e}|
#|   a|   b|null|   e|{null, null}|
#|   a|   z|   d|null|{null, null}|
#|   a|null|null|null|{null, null}|
#+----+----+----+----+------------+
```

**`Method2:`**

If you want only `null` col5 value then use this method and no schema consistency for `col5`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([('a',None,'d','e'),
                            ('a','b',None,'e'),
                            ('a','z','d',None),
                            ('a',None,None,None)],
                           ['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
df.show(10,False)

df.withColumn("col5",
when((col("col3").isNotNull()) & (col("col4").isNotNull()),to_json(struct(*[col(c) for c in ["col3", "col4"]]))).\
otherwise(to_json(lit(None)))).\
show(10)
#+----+----+----+----+-----------------------+
#|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5                   |
#+----+----+----+----+-----------------------+
#|a   |null|d   |e   |{"col3":"d","col4":"e"}|
#|a   |b   |null|e   |null                   |
#|a   |z   |d   |null|null                   |
#|a   |null|null|null|null                   |
#+----+----+----+----+-----------------------+
```